# JSTL tag not translate in HTML

Tags: html, jstl, tags, translate

My imports :

```
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
  xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
```

My JSTL Code :

```
  <h:outputLabel value="YESS" >
  <fmt:formatNumber value="0.25" type="percent"></fmt:formatNumber>
```

---

HTML generated code:

```
  <label>YESS</label>
  <fmt:formatNumber value="0.25" type="percent"></fmt:formatNumber>
```

The generated code show that the JSTL core is translate in HTML.
But the JSTL "fmt" is not translate in HTML.

More information:

```
    <fmt:ErrorInThisFunctionName value="0.25" type="percent" />    ===> generate an error
```

- I work on Tomcat 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Pierre said, and also,

Try `xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"`

Check web.xml for

```
<web-app version="2.4"
                 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

Answer (score 1):

suggestion:

- check your TLD file.
- check your header  (DTD, attributes) in your web.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the normal JSP syntax and not the XML-based syntax try using

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
```

The URI for core taglib is invalid. It should be `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core` as per its [TLD](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html), with `/jsp`. The URI for format taglib is perfectly fine as per its [TLD](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html).

Does the core taglib work in any way? If it doesn't work as well, then it simply means that JSTL is not installed at all. Tomcat does not ship with JSTL by default. You need to download [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) and put it in `/WEB-INF/lib` of your webapp. That's all. Do **not** extract the JAR file and put its loose contents (TLD files and so on) in the classpath as some poor tutorials suggests. It will only get worse. If you already did so, you should cleanup. **Only** putting the JSTL JAR in classpath is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem where I would basically declare  and it wouldn't get translated into HTML (basically, instead of printing the variable, the entire c:out was printed in the html source).  I had forgotten to add this dependency to maven:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

(If the xml doesn't print, the groupId is taglibs, the artifactId is standard, and the version is 1.1.2